# Проблема после обновления ansible

Tags: debian, развертывание, ansible

Добрый день!
Обновил ansible с версии 1.7.2 до 2.0.0.
До обновления конфиги не менялись - все деплойменты работали.
Новый ансибл выдает ошибку синтаксиса:

```
ERROR! no action detected in task

The error appears to have been in '/....../ansible/roles/preconf/tasks/main.yml': line 3, column 3, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:


- name: install software
  ^ here
```

Часть конфига:

```
---
- name: install software
  apt: 
    name:"{{ item }}"
    state:present
    update_cache:yes
    cache_valid_time:3600
  with_items:
    - sudo
    - git
    - mc
    - ntp
    - ntpdate
    - wget
    - mlocate
    - curl
  tags: [preconf, soft]
```

И понять не могу в упор что он от меня хочет...почему не видит задачи на выполнение?
Может проблема в этом:

```
$ ansible --version
ansible 2.0.0
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = None
```

Как в конфиге задать путь к модулям

Comment: Как обновляли ?

Comment: git clone https://github.com/ansible/ansible.git && cd ./ansible && sudo make && sudo make install.

Comment: вот похоже на ваш кейс https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/11206#issuecomment-110468576

Comment: Спасибо! Помогло :) запускал апдейт модулей, но забыл после этого сборку снова сделать

Comment: В последнее время у нас тут нередки вопросы про ansible. Заходите почаще )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Спасибо еще раз пользователю [dizballanze](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/176062/dizballanze) за подсказку
Проблема решается следующим образом:

```
cd ./ansible && git submodule update --init --recursive \
make && make install
```